# Keeping gridview column index original order

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a dynamic gridview with the following functions:

- You can use checkboxes to choose which columns will be visible. This is achieved like this:

  ```
      if (!chkTBDataRdo.Checked)
          grd.Columns[11].Visible = false;
      else
          grd.Columns[11].Visible = true;
  ```
- You can Drag&Drop labels around to choose in which order the columns will be displayed.

  ```
      if (hColumnList.Value != "")
      {
          string[] ordine = hColumnList.Value.Split(',');

          for (int i = 0; i < ordine.Length; i++)
          {
              var columnToMove = grd.Columns[Convert.ToInt32(ordine[i])];
              grd.Columns.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(ordine[i]));
              grd.Columns.Insert(i, columnToMove);
          }

      }
  ```

`hColumnList` is a hidden field used to keep the field order you've set.
Everything's working fine, however when you perform a search and reorder the grid, the indexes used to perform `RemoveAt` and `Insert` no longer match the original ones, and subsequent searches fail miserably because of the mismatch.

I tried rebuilding the grid every time before moving the columns around, like so:

```
grd.DataSource = null; //I tried with the original DataSource aswell.
grd.DataBind();
```

I also tried storing the original grid in a Session variable, like this:

```
Session["grd_Orig"] = grd;
```

But so far none of this has worked: the grid always breaks at 2nd reorder and it looks like it's not rebuilding its original indexes.
Is there another way to do this?
Data comes from a MSSQL Database, and I'm not allowed to use any 3rd party component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding `ViewStateMode="Disabled"` property to the gridview.